# How can I draw 3d hyperplane to illustrate decision boundary using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, logistic-regression

I have dataframe df which has 3d input data : x1, x2, x3 and target t. I used logistic regression to create decision boundary

```
a0 + a1 * x1 + a2 * x2 + a3 * x3 = 0
```

I was wondering if there is a way to draw 3d hyperplane (along with 3d input data) using ggplot to illustrate decision boundary created by logistic regression.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have a true 3D plot in ggplot2, but there are ways to represent a 3d plane using contour lines or colour fills. Here's an example using a coloured raster layer to represent a plane.

I assume from the question you want the decision boundary to be where the probability is 0.5 (i.e. the log odds = 0)

First we need a logistic regression model, so in the absence of any data in the question, let's create some that will allow us a nice example:

```r
# Create dummy data for logistic regression
set.seed(69)

x1       <- sample(100, 1000, TRUE)
x2       <- sample(100, 1000, TRUE)
x3       <- sample(100, 1000, TRUE)
log_odds <- -1 + 0.02 * x1 + 0.005 * x2 - 0.03 * x3 + rnorm(1000, 0, 2)
odds     <- exp(log_odds)
probs    <- odds/(1 + odds)
y        <- rbinom(1000, 1, probs)
df       <- data.frame(y, x1, x2, x3)
```

Now we have a binary outcome, `y`, whose value is dependent on the values of the three independent variables `x1`, `x2` and `x3`, so we can run a logistic regression and grab its coefficients:

```r
# Run logistic regression and extract coefficients
logistic_model <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = df, family = binomial)
summary(logistic_model)
#> 
#> Call:
#> glm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, family = binomial, data = df)
#> 
#> Deviance Residuals: 
#>     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
#> -1.5058  -0.8689  -0.6296   1.1264   2.3669  
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept) -0.888782   0.232728  -3.819 0.000134 ***
#> x1           0.012369   0.002562   4.828 1.38e-06 ***
#> x2           0.008031   0.002478   3.241 0.001191 ** 
#> x3          -0.020676   0.002560  -8.076 6.67e-16 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
#> 
#>     Null deviance: 1235.0  on 999  degrees of freedom
#> Residual deviance: 1129.9  on 996  degrees of freedom
#> AIC: 1137.9
#> 
#> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

coefs <- coef(logistic_model)
```

Our plot is going to show `x1` on the x axis and `x2` on the y axis. The colour at each point (x1, x2) will be the value of `x3` that produces log odds of 0. We can get this by rearranging the formula `a0 + a1 * x1 + a2 * x2 + a3 * x3 = 0` that you showed in the question:

```r
# Create a function that returns the value of x3 at p = 0.5, given x1 and x2
find_x3 <- function(x1, x2) (-coefs[1] -coefs[2] * x1 - coefs[3] * x2)/coefs[4]
```

Now we can create a data frame that contains all values of `x1` and `x2` between 1 and 100, and find the appropriate value of `x3` that gives log odds of 0 for each point on this grid:

```
# Create a data frame to plot the 3d plane where p = 0.5
plot_df    <- expand.grid(x2 = 1:100, x1 = 1:100)
plot_df$x3 <- find_x3(plot_df$x1, plot_df$x2)
head(plot_df)
#>   x2 x1        x3
#> 1  1  1 -41.99975
#> 2  2  1 -41.61133
#> 3  3  1 -41.22291
#> 4  4  1 -40.83450
#> 5  5  1 -40.44608
#> 6  6  1 -40.05766
```

We can confirm this gives us the values of our decision boundary by running `predict` with this data frame as `newdata`. The values should all be 0 (or very close to 0):

```r
head(predict(logistic_model, newdata = plot_df))
#>             1             2             3             4             5            
#>  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00 -1.110223e-16  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
```

Good.

Finally, we can plot the result with a colorful divergent scale to show the values of `x1`, `x2` and `x3` that together give your decision boundary:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(plot_df, aes(x1, x2, fill = x3)) + 
  geom_raster() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("deepskyblue4", "forestgreen", "gold", "red")) +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

If you're looking for a genuine 3d perspective plot, you could try base R's `persp` function:

```r
persp(x = 1:100, y = 1:100, z = matrix(plot_df$x3, ncol = 100), 
      xlab = "x1", ylab = "x2", zlab = "x3", 
      theta = -45, , phi = 25, d = 5,
      col = "gold", border = "orange", 
      ticktype = "detailed")
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2020-08-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot @Allan for taking all the effort. Can you please tell me if it Is possible to add input data along with decision boundary for better illustration in 3d perspective plot.